# sap.m.select values not selecting correclty

Tags: javascript, html, select, sapui5

I have a  sap.m.inputlistitem  with content as sap.m.select.
The list and select  are binded to a JSON model.
The list is rendered with select(dropdown) values properly but the problem is......

when I select another element than default value in dropdown/select ,the value is not getting selected ,

ex:

lets say i had a dropdown with 3 values / 3 select options

- sapui5
- backbone
- angualrjs

now, when i select backbone, from dropdown list ,its selected ,but when i want to select sapui5 again its not selected...

any ideas ????

Answer (score 0):

sap.m.inputlistitem should not be a valid aggregation type for items aggregation of sap.m.Select.

[UI5 Document for Select](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Select.html)

Aggregations
items (default aggregation) : sap.ui.core.Item[]